# Making Nginx rewrite backend responses

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, proxypass

I have a few services running on other servers that delivers a webapplications on http://someLocalIp:80 without SSL. I want to wrap this in ssl and make it public on https://nginxServer-globalIp/deliver/

I am able to see the backend-service like this but this will obviously break all links and references because now "/deliver/" must be a prefix. I dont understand how to go about using rewrite, because the rewrite seems (to me) to be used mostly to change requests and not replies from the backend. Is this at all possible? :)

current config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/some.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/some.key;
    location /deliver {
            proxy_pass http://someLocalIp;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding / on the end of proxy_pass (as many answers suggest) but this creates a blank response, as if the backend service does not deliver anything to nginx.

Also, changing the backend to match the "/deliver" prefix is not as easy as it sounds, so I hope it is possible to do this without doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse-proxy has its limitations. Rewriting every embedded URL (hyperlink, image, resource link) would be expensive anyway.

As you surmised, the `nginx` proxy module can rewrite the request and can rewrite the `location` field in a redirect response. But it otherwise leaves the enclosed HTML document untouched.

However, I have read that there is an [Apache module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) that will work if you really need to go down that route.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'd rather fix the app than go with apache :)